# Is it worth using Cat6 cables with existing Cat5e wiring?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, cable

We are currently in the process of installing a new Wi-Fi repeater in our house. Our house was built with Cat5e cabling in the walls, conveniently going from the location of our current router to our new bridge. Since I'm not about to go into my walls and change out the Cat5e cabling for Cat6 cabling, is it worth connecting the access points to the wall tap using a Cat6 cable, or do you have to go completely Cat6 for any benefit?

Answer (score 1):

CAT6 has no value in this case. The only case where you might get SOME benefit is between two devices on your network.

For example if you have a firewall box connected to a switch and then to the access point there might be some benefit to using CAT6 between them. But this is fanciful since all three of those functions are probably in the same box.

But going from a device for some distance on CAT5e and the switching to CAT6 will get you nothing since the CAT5e will throttle the speed down below what CAT6 can do, anyway.

The good news is that if you're using 802.11b, a or g the CAT5e should be way faster than the wireless, anyway so it won't make any difference.